# Symfony2 - Showing results with different show routes

Tags: symfony, search, show, routes

I have a web app setup using different categories with a one to many relationship to post.

This is fine, and I am showing it as a `category1`, `category2`, `category3` prefix /{slug}.

My question is I have search results that returns posts from different categories that use different showactions.

**How can I set this up so that after the search results are displayed, I can select on them even though they are using different showactions? (Without using a universal route like `/{slug}` minus the beginning prefix of category type.)**

e.g., the following will not work for posts under Category2, or Category 3

```
<h1><a href="{{ path('acme_demo_category1_show', { slug: post.slug }) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
```

**showCategory1Action**

```
/**
 * @Route("/category1/{slug}", name="acme_demo_category1_show")
 * @Template("AcmeDemoBundle:Category:show.html.twig")
 */
public function showCategory1Action($slug)
{
    $article = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Category1')
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'slug' => $slug
        ));

    if (null === $article) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Post was not found');
    }

    return array(
        'article' => $article,
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (see comments)**

So what you want is to have urls that reflect a post's category, ie: football/launch-world-cup.html
To do that you need to have a slug property for the Post entity as well as for the Category entity.

Your routing should look something like this

```
acme_demo_show:
    pattern:  /{catslug}/{postslug}.html
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:show  }
```

Your controller's `showAction` method will then take in 2 parameters and in twig you can use

```
<h1><a href="{{ path('acme_demo_show' , { catslug: post.category.slug, postslug: post.slug }) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
```

A post having the slug world-cup-launch posted in the category having the slug football would then result in www.mywebsite.com/football/world-cup-launch.html

Comment: So what would best practice be? Use a universal show route that works for everything? I've seen some sites that use different prefixes before the slug and wanted to do something like that.

Comment: Yep. Those websites use two slugs, one for the category (ie: 'news'), one for the post (ie: the-post-title.html). Which would give {{ path('acme_demo_show', { postslug: post.slug, catslug: post.category.slug }) }} and end up as /news/the-post-title.html. Unless you need specific controllers for each category that's the way to go.

Comment: I see, can you update your answer with an example setup and I'll accept it. So I'll need to add a new property to category entity called category slug?

Comment: You might also want to take a look at doctrine's sluggable extension it is a great way to generate slug from the post title.

Comment: You mean the one from the stof bundle?

Comment: Stof's bundle integrates them into SF2 yes.